# Trying to replace link with hyperlink in textarea using javascript gives array error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Whenever user type in textarea and post some link in it, I immediately want to change it to link like stackoverflow.com does here whenever anyone types https://stackoverflow.com/?q=and+message+continues+till+end but whenever anyone will pass any non-link text it will come back to text look...

here is my try, what i have done, before i post it below , let me tell you i am not javascript student, i am just trying to cut paste and use my other programming logic and trying to make it happen. So, whenever you reply, consider my no-solid-javascript background.

Thanks

My Try below :-

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
        return regexp.test(s);
    }

$('#status').keyup(function() {
    var value = $("#status").val();
    var words = value.split(" ");
    for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        var n = isUrl(words[i]);
        if (n)  {
            var deadLink = '<a href="'+words[i]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'+words[i]+'</a>';
            words[i].replace(words[i], deadLink);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is not working, I am not getting any error here, but when i use it without array indexing like below I am getting array error:-

```
for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
{
    var n = isUrl(words);
    if (n)  {
    var deadLink = '<a href="http://google.com/search?q='+words+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'+words+'</a>';
    words.replace(words, deadLink);
    }
}
```

Any way to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, just calling replace aloe has no effect: `words[i].replace(words[i], deadLink);`. You have to assign its result to something, like (and I don't know this is what you mean): `words[i] = words[i].replace(words[i], deadLink);`

Comment: nope.. its not working too.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problems:

- Your `replace()` calls had no effect as you weren't assigning them to anything.
- You didn't use the resulting `words` array - you just processed it and... nothing.

Some changes I made:

- Added one line to escape the typed text:

  ```
  var value = $('<div/>').text(nonEscapedValue).html();
  ```
- Changed `replace()`'s line to assign `replace()`'s result:

  ```
  words[i] = words[i].replace(words[i], deadLink);
  ```
- Finally added a line to put the processed array in to a `div`:

  ```
  $("#myResultDiv").html(words.join(" "));
  ```

Final code ([**check jsfiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/TAey7/2/)):

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
    return regexp.test(s);
}
$('#status').keyup(function() {
    var nonEscapedValue = $("#status").val();
    // added line below to escape typed text
    var value = $('<div/>').text(nonEscapedValue).html();
    var words = value.split(" ");
    for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        var n = isUrl(words[i]);
        if (n)  {
            var deadLink = '<a href="'+words[i]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'+words[i]+'</a>';
            // changed line below to assign replace()'s result
            words[i] = words[i].replace(words[i], deadLink);
        }
    }
    // added line below to put the result in to the div #myResultDiv
    $("#myResultDiv").html(words.join(" "));
});
```

Hopefully this will help you towards your goal.

Comment: oh my god, you are so so awesome... I was not appending it :| .. thanks so much bro.. :)

Comment: Oh! there is 1 slight error, when i type hello http://facebook.com <script>alert('xss');</script> and brooom!! you know what it does.. is there any escape method for it..

Comment: Yes. `var escapedValue = $('<div/>').text(nonEscapedValue).html();` will do it. I'm using it in the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/TAey7/2/

Comment: oh believe it or not.. i am copy pasting your exact code and its not working in my localhost, but surprisingly its working in jsfiddle...

Comment: array of errors actually :P 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token << [http://localhost/page.php:1]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < [http://localhost/page.php:1]

Comment: Uhm, this is strange. Maybe looking directly at the exact file the fiddle uses will help: http://fiddle.jshell.net/acdcjunior/TAey7/2/show/ ? Does it help?

Comment: Strange... I copy pasted the whole source in my localhost and ran the code http://localhsot/trynow.php it works.. but the same code is not working in my page.php which actually inherits bootstrap framework and nothing else..

Comment: got the error... i am also using other js code with textarea like auto-resizing and character counting, ... removing those js code solved the issue.. now i need to do some more checking to make it work with those js code.. too...:(.
Anyways thanks once again bro..

Comment: If you get stuck, maybe you could post the part on a fiddle. I can help you more!

Comment: nope it will pop alert when typing this <script>alert('xss');</script>

Comment: This line: `content = $(this).val();` You have to escape it: `content = $(this).val(); content = $('<div/>').text(content).html();`. Because  this line `hiddenDiv.html(content + '<br class="lbr">');` is placing the text as raw HTML, thus executing the `<script>` tag.  Here's the fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/UQYjJ/5/